# list adapters addresses and mask/prefix, both IPv4 and IPv6 (GetAdaptersAddresses)

Tags: c, winapi, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I am tasked with listing all unicast interfaces (IP-address & subnet via netmask (IPv4) or prefix length (IPv6)) on the local machine. Being new to win32 API, I am reading [GetAdaptersAddress docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses). There is an example which is quite clear:

- call `GetAdaptersAddresses` with increasing buffer size until the results fit into the allocated memory chunk
- iterate over returned linked list of [PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh) (`pCurrAddresses`):

  - iterate over [PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_unicast_address_lh) `pCurrAddresses->FirstUnicastAddresses` linked list to retrieve all IP addresses ([SOCKET_ADDRESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-socket_address) and its [LPSOCKADDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2) `Address->lpSockAddr` member); it is a `sockaddr_in*` or `sockaddr_in6*` depending on `lpSockAddr.sa_family` (`AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`)

At this moment, I have IP addresses.

How about netmask/prefix? This seems to be what [PIP_ADAPTER_PREFIX_XP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_prefix_xp) (and its `SOCKET_ADDRESS Address` field) is about. That is another linked list, accessible from `PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` through `->FirstPrefix`.

Unhelpfully, [the docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh) that prefixes may not be ordered the same as addresses:

> In addition, the linked IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS structures pointed
> to by the FirstUnicastAddress member and the linked
> IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX structures pointed to by the FirstPrefix member are
> maintained as separate internal linked lists by the operating system.
> As a result, the order of linked IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS structures
> pointed to by the FirstUnicastAddress member does not have any
> relationship with the order of linked IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX structures
> pointed to by the FirstPrefix member.

What is the solution? Am I missing something obvious?

Some code (e.g. [zeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/blob/master/src/ziflist.c#L284)) only uses, for each adapter, the first unicast address and the first prefix. Is that approach safe?  Am I going to miss interfaces?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18100761/1606345 ?

Comment: @DavidRanieri not really, [GetAdaptersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) is IPv4-only.

Comment: IPv6 netmask? IPv6 doesn't use net masks anymore, always CIDR notation.

Comment: @StriveSun For IPv6, network prefix length; I will adjust the wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::FirstPrefix` field gives you a list of subnets/prefixes that are assigned to the adapter, but as the documentation states, `GetAdaptersAddresses()` doesn't tell you which specific IP address on the adapter corresponds to which subnet/prefix.  So, to determine each IP address's particular subnet/prefix, you have to look at the individual entries in the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::FirstUnicastAddresses` list.

On Windows Vista and later, the `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS::OnLinkPrefixLength` field provides the length of the IPv4 subnet mask for an `AF_INET` address, and the length of the IPv6 prefix for an `AF_INET6` address.  For IPv4, the length can be passed to the [`ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-convertlengthtoipv4mask) function if you need the actual subnet mask.

On Windows XP, the `OnLinkPrefixLength` field does not exist. Fortunately, an `AF_INET` address's IPv4 subnet mask can be retrieved by calling the [`GetIpAddrTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getipaddrtable) function and then looking for the IP address in the table (in the `MIB_IPADDRROW::dwAddr` field - the subnet mask will be in the `MIB_IPADDRROW::dwMask` field).

I don't know how to get an `AF_INET6` address's IPv6 prefix length on XP, if you need that.

Comment: Thank you, this was immensely helpful.

For the record, under XP, interface with multiple addresses will only have the preferred addres show up in `GetAdaptersAddresses`. XP+IPv6 is for the moment not needed.